# find the position of the next highest of the given element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a descending order sorted array, where I need to get the position of the given element if found in an array, if not found then return the position of the next higher element. For example

if we pass [10,11,10], the expected result is [12, 12, 12] because 10<12 && 11<12 && 10<12

Hence altogether

```
var arr = [
    [18, 12, 6],
    [16, 12, 9],
    [15, 11, 6],
    [14, 10, 7],
    [13, 12, 4],
    [13, 11, 2],
    [12, 12, 12],
    [12, 12, 7],
    [12, 10, 9],
    [12, 9, 6],
    [12, 9, 2],
    [12, 8, 8],
    [11, 9, 1],
    [10, 10, 10],
    [9, 7, 3],
    [8, 6, 5],
    [6, 6, 6],
    [6, 4, 4],
    [4, 4, 4]
];

var g = [10,11,10];
var a=[],b=[],c=[];

for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    a.push(arr[i][0]);
    b.push(arr[i][1]);
    c.push(arr[i][2]);
}

console.log(getPos(g)) // expected result is [12,12,12]
```

Comment: you'll need to use `.findIndex` I guess - since the array is in reverse numerical order, it'll be a little complicated, but easily doable

Comment: Need not be reverse order, anything works

Comment: For your input of `g = [10,11,10]`, what is your expected output?

Comment: The positon of  [12, 12, 12], since its being the next greatest that covers 10,11,10

Comment: I updated the question for better clarity

Comment: What should the result be if `g = [13, 10, 10]`?  It doesn't exist on the array and there is no entry where all three value are greater than all three g values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the array is sorted in descending order, the simplest way to solve this is probably just to iterate backwards over the array until you find a subarray whose elements are all greater than or equal to every element in the input array:

```js
const arr = [
  [18, 12, 6],
  [16, 12, 9],
  [15, 11, 6],
  [14, 10, 7],
  [13, 12, 4],
  [13, 11, 2],
  [12, 12, 12],
  [12, 12, 7],
  [12, 10, 9],
  [12, 9, 6],
  [12, 9, 2],
  [12, 8, 8],
  [11, 9, 1],
  [10, 10, 10],
  [9, 7, 3],
  [8, 6, 5],
  [6, 6, 6],
  [6, 4, 4],
  [4, 4, 4]
];

function getPos(arr, inp) {
  for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i][0] >= inp[0] && arr[i][1] >= inp[1] && arr[i][2] >= inp[2]) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
}

console.log(getPos(arr, [10, 11, 10]));
console.log(getPos(arr, [10, 10, 10]));
console.log(getPos(arr, [1, 1, 1]));
```

You can write this more concisely using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), but this has the downside of touching every element in the array, even after finding the result:

```
const getPos = (inp) => arr.reverse().reduce((c, v) =>
  !c && v[0] >= inp[0] && v[1] >= inp[1] && v[2] >= inp[2] ? v : c, null);
```

This piece of code can also be modified to work if the array is not sorted. In this case, since all elements have to be looked at, there is no penalty to using `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [
  [16, 12, 9],
  [11, 9, 1],
  [15, 11, 6],
  [6, 6, 6],
  [13, 12, 4],
  [4, 4, 5],
  [13, 11, 2],
  [18, 12, 6],
  [12, 12, 12],
  [12, 12, 7],
  [12, 10, 9],
  [12, 9, 6],
  [12, 9, 2],
  [12, 8, 8],
  [14, 10, 7],
  [10, 10, 10],
  [9, 7, 3],
  [8, 6, 5],
  [6, 4, 4],
  [4, 6, 4]
];

const getPos = (inp) => arr.reduce((c, v) =>
  v[0] >= inp[0] && v[1] >= inp[1] && v[2] >= inp[2] &&
  (!c ||
    v[0] < c[0] ||
    v[0] == c[0] && v[1] < c[1] ||
    v[0] == c[0] && v[1] == c[1] && v[2] < c[2]) ?
  v : c,
  null);

console.log(getPos([10, 11, 10]));
console.log(getPos([10, 10, 10]));
console.log(getPos([1, 1, 1]));
```

Comment: What would happen if `g = [10, 10, 10]`?  That exists on the array and the OP wants its position if it does exist, and only to find the **next highest** if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @ATD thanks for pointing that out, the `>` should have been `>=`

Comment: Well, yes, there is that!  However, wouldn't your code return the **first** item that is >= g.  If g was, say, [1, 1, 1], would it return [18, 12, 6] (the first item found that is >= g) or [4, 4, 4] (the next highest above g)?

Comment: Ah, yes, but the OP has said that it is not necessarily in reverse order - *Need not be reverse order, anything works*

Comment: @ATD the question starts: "I have a descending order sorted array" so I have answered based on that...

Comment: @CodeGuy fyi, I've added another solution which will work if the array is not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have been helpful

```js
var arr = [
    [18, 12, 6],
    [16, 12, 9],
    [15, 11, 6],
    [14, 10, 7],
    [13, 12, 4],
    [13, 11, 2],
    [12, 12, 12],
    [12, 12, 7],
    [12, 10, 9],
    [12, 9, 6],
    [12, 9, 2],
    [12, 8, 8],
    [11, 9, 1],
    [10, 10, 10],
    [9, 7, 3],
    [8, 6, 5],
    [6, 6, 6],
    [6, 4, 4],
    [4, 4, 4]
];

var g = [10, 11, 10]; // -> [12, 12, 12]


for (i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i][0] >= g[0] && arr[i][1] >= g[1] && arr[i][2] >= g[2]) {
        console.log(i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `g = [1,1,1]` this will return `[18,12,6]`, not `[4,4,4]`

Comment: @Nick, Thanks for your attention! I fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Given that the array could be in any order - your comment: *Need not be reverse order, anything works*, you will need to loop through the array and keep track of the item that is next higher than your given g values.  If g is found, then return its position.  If g is not found, return the next highest item found.  The only question that remains is what to do if g is not found AND there are no entries where all three values are >= all three g values.

Something like:

```js
var arr = [
  [16, 12, 9],
  [11, 9, 1],
  [15, 11, 6],
  [6, 6, 6],
  [13, 12, 4],
  [4, 4, 5],
  [13, 11, 2],
  [18, 12, 6],
  [12, 12, 12],
  [12, 12, 7],
  [12, 10, 9],
  [12, 9, 6],
  [12, 9, 2],
  [12, 8, 8],
  [14, 10, 7],
  [10, 10, 10],
  [9, 7, 3],
  [8, 6, 5],
  [6, 4, 4],
  [4, 6, 4]
];



//var g = [10,11,10];
//var g = [13,11,10];
//var g = [5, 6, 7];
var g = [1,1,1];

var found = false;
var pos = 0;
var last = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i][0] == g[0] && arr[i][1] == g[1] && arr[i][2] == g[2]) {
    found = true;
    pos = i;
    break;
  } else if (arr[i][0] >= g[0] && arr[i][1] >= g[1] && arr[i][2] >= g[2]) {
    if (last.length == 0) {
      last = arr[i];
      pos = i;
    } else if (arr[i][0] < last[0]) {
      last = arr[i];
      pos = i;
    } else if (arr[i][0] == last[0] && arr[i][1] < last[1]) {
      last = arr[i];
      pos = i;
    } else if (arr[i][0] == last[0] && arr[i][1] == last[1] && arr[i][2] < last[2]) {
      last = arr[i];
      pos = i;
    }
  }
}

if (found) {
  console.log(g, " found at " + pos);
} else if (last.length == 0) {
  console.log(g, " NOT found and no entry has all three values that are higher");
} else {
  console.log(g, " NOT found, next highest is " + last + " at position " + pos);
}
```

Comment: Well, it works but it does look awful - if you can think of a neater way to do this, any comments welcome.

Comment: I went off and tried to do that, during which I discovered this doesn't actually work properly. If you shuffle the input (as I've done in the snippet I've added to my answer) you'll see that for an input of `[1,1,1]` it returns `[6,4,4]` when it should be `[4,4,4]`

Comment: I've updated my code to use the same array order as yours and to tweak the final if test. (using `<=` instead of just `<`

Comment: My last value is `[4, 6, 4]`, if you change yours to match it returns `[4,6,4]` which is not correct, it should be `[4, 4, 5]`.

Comment: Try it now - I think I've worked out what was going wrong.

Comment: Yeah, now the code is the same as in the snippet I added, so it should be good to go.